# Pyhunspell installation in virtualnev

Tags: linux, python-3.x, virtualenv, hunspell

I have a problem with installation of pyhunspell bindings for hunspell library in python 3.2 virtualenv. I downloaded hunspell from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hunspell/files/Hunspell/1.3.2/hunspell-1.3.2.tar.gz/download?use_mirror=cznic). I issued `./configure` and `make` and it run all right. I avoided however to do `make install` because my purpose is to install it on virtualenv on a web server, where I have no root permissions.

Thus I downloaded [pyhunspell bindings](https://code.google.com/p/pyhunspell/downloads/detail?name=hunspell-0.1.tar.gz&can=2&q=) and unzipped it to the directory, where hunspell is made. I modified `include_dir` path in `setup.py` by adding correct destination and applied the [patch](https://pyhunspell.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=70000000&name=python3.patch&token=wbzF3VPBIu_URrCjRYCQpYqNGXU:1387713515633) which allows to build pyhunspell with Python 3. Then I ran `python setup.py install` (having activated the target virtualenv before), but I got this:

```
$ python setupy.py install
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'hunspell' extension
gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -D_LINUX -I./src/hunspell -I/usr/include/hunspell -I/usr/include/python3.2mu -c hunspell.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.2/hunspell.o -Wall
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2
gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.2/hunspell.o -lhunspell-1.2 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.2/hunspell.cpython-32mu.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhunspell-1.2
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

It seems that linker cannot link something because it looks for it in system path, while I didn't install the library in the system. Can someone wiser than me in the arcana of C devise any workaround to this issue?

I'll add that I have no access to the real server yet, but I know it will have the system pretty much similar to my local one (Debian 7.0 Wheezy), so I decided to give it a try before I actually log in to the server. Is it possible that the library compiled on my computer would work also on the server, assuming it would also be some (stable probably) version of Debian?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to build Hunspell. Install the Wheezy packages [libhunspell-1.3-0](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libhunspell-1.3-0) and [libhunspell-dev](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libhunspell-dev). It should work with HunSpell 1.3. Just modify [setup.py](https://code.google.com/p/pyhunspell/source/browse/trunk/setup.py) to use `libraries = ['hunspell']`.

---

FYI, the posted patch has a problem. It adds the methods of `HunSpell` as module functions. These receive the module as the first argument instead of the expected `HunSpell` instance. For example, if you call `hunspell.spell`, the process will probably segfault when it tries to use `self->handle`. You should fix the `PyModuleDef` to get rid of these mal-functions. Change line 273 of hunspell.c to use `NULL` instead of `HunSpell_methods`.

Comment: Strange, because I looked for hunspell in the repository and found nothing. But now, as you provided full package names, I see they're there indeed. I hopethey will be installed on the server. Thank you also for information about the patch. I'll fix it.